# Rewrite match only first occurrence

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting

I want my rewrite rule to catch only first match and ignore the rest

Current behaviour

```
https://example.com/oliver.stack => oliver
https://example.com/oliver.stackoliver.stack => oliver.stackoliver
```

Desired behaviour

```
https://example.com/oliver.stack => oliver
https://example.com/oliver.stackoliver.stack => oliver
```

Nginx rewrite rule

```
location ~ .stack$ {
        rewrite ^/(.*).stack$ /vid.php?v=$1;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`stack$` will match "stack" *at the end of the line* (final `$`). Moreover, `.*` is greedy: it will try to match the longest string. `.*?` is the non greedy version:

```
rewrite ^/(.*?)\.stack /vid.php?v=$1;
```

Comment: Thanks for the explaination